# Architecture decisions relating to multiple Automation Accounts per subscription

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-automation

As an MSP, we manage multiple customer subscriptions through Azure Lighthouse.

Historically we've used a single Automation Account per subscription to contain solutions such as runbooks related to the [Start/Stop v1 solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management), Automation-based [Update Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/overview), Inventory, and Change Tracking. This Automation Account is also linked to a single Log Analytics workspace per subscription.

We've since deployed [Start/Stop v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/start-stop-vms/overview), which uses LogicApps and Azure Functions. We now have a requirement to, as part of stopping and starting some VMs, stop and start some services on the machines itself. I plan on doing this through (PowerShell) Azure Automation Runbooks, which would only stop a VM if the runbook has successfully stopped a service on it.

My question relates to whether a single monolithic Automation Account is the way to go, or whether there are any considerations to be taken if we were to implement multiple Automation Accounts.

(I've noticed [Best practice to deploy Azure Automation Account Runbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496304/best-practice-to-deploy-azure-automation-account-runbooks), but that's over a year ago. Things might have changed in the mean time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice related question which you have mentioned still holds good i.e., 2 major attributes to consider are pricing and logical resource allocation. One other attribute to keep in mind while deciding whether to go with single or multiple automation accounts is the limits i.e., if you go with single automation account then does the traffic in your environment or the activities that your automation account does reach the limits mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#automation-limits)? If yes, then go for multiple automation accounts approach.